# Waiting with gcloud on "detect-text-pdf" operation

Tags: google-colaboratory, gcloud

I'm running a `detect-text-pdf` with gcloud:

```
$ gcloud ml vision detect-text-pdf gs://my-bucket/pdfs/D.pdf gs://my-bucket/pdfs/D
```

which results in an output like:

```json
{
  "name": "projects/PROJECT_ID/operations/OPERATION_ID"
}
```

Where `PROJECT_ID` is the project and `OPERATION_ID` is a hex number.

How can I wait for the operation to complete?
I've tried:

```
gcloud services operations wait OPERATION_ID
```

But I get the error:

```
ERROR: gcloud crashed (ArgumentTypeError): Invalid value 'OPERATION_ID': Operation format should be operations/namespace.id
```

I'm running from a colab notebook if this helps.

Comment: Have you tried `gcloud services operations wait operations/OPERATION_ID`?

Comment: @DazWilkin Thanks!. Yes, I tried that - same result (crash)

Comment: @lazy1 Could you please edit your question and share the code you're using to have a [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @RogelioMonter You're right! Done.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** *How can I wait for the operation to complete?*

You can not use the [`gcloud services operations wait`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/services/operations/wait) command, but you can get operation status as shown in the documentation [Working with long-running operations](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/operation-status)

---

From the [`gcloud ml vision detect-text-pdf`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ml/vision/detect-text-pdf) reference:

> **API REFERENCE**
>
> This command uses the  `vision/v1`  API. The full documentation for this API can be found at:  https://cloud.google.com/vision/

Also, as shown  in the documentation [Detect text in files (PDF/TIFF)](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pdf#document_text_detection_requests):

> A successful  `asyncBatchAnnotate`  request returns a response with a single name field:
>
> ```
> {  
>     "name":  "projects/usable-auth-library/operations/**1efec2285bd442df**"  
> }
> ```
>
> This name represents a long-running operation with an associated ID (for example,  `1efec2285bd442df`), which can be queried using the  `v1.operations`  API.
>
> To retrieve your Vision annotation response, send a GET request to the  `v1.operations`  endpoint, passing the operation ID in the URL:
>
> ```
> GET https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/operations/operation-id
> ```

As shown both in the reference and the documentation, these are long running operations which use the `v1.operations`  API. Therefore, you can not use the [`gcloud services operations wait`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/services/operations/wait) command, but you can get operation status as shown in the documentation [Working with long-running operations](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/operation-status):

> Several operations you request are long-running, ... These types of requests will return a JSON with an operation ID that you can use to get the status of the operation.

In section [Get an operation code samples](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/operation-status#get-an-operation-code-samples), there are some instructions to request the status of your long running operations.

> HTTP method and URL:
>
> ```bash
> GET https://automl.googleapis.com/v1/projects/project-id/locations/us-central1/operations/operation-id
> ```
>
> To send your request using [curl](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/operation-status#curl), execute the following command:
>
> ```bash
> curl -X GET \  
> -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \  
> "https://automl.googleapis.com/v1/projects/project-id/locations/us-central1/operations/operation-id"
> ```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm no longer working for this client so can't check if your solution actualy solve the problem (sorry). Will keep it in mind for next time.